# ECMAScript Primitives: Immutability vs Value Type

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript

Coming from languages like C++, Java or PHP I've learned that there are **Value Types** and **Reference Types**. Value Types store values **directly in the variable** (in a box / memory location). Whereas Reference Types store **a reference to an Object** in memory.

This makes perfect sense and seems like a simple mental model to deal with.

About primitives in JavaScript, MDN has [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive?retiredLocale=de) to say:

> All primitives are immutable; that is, they cannot be altered. It is
> important not to confuse a primitive itself with a variable assigned a
> primitive value. The variable may be reassigned to a new value, but
> the existing value can not be changed in the ways that objects,
> arrays, and functions can be altered. The language does not offer
> utilities to mutate primitive values.

While this is undoubtedly true, why do you have to emphasize **immutability** when it basically comes for free implicitly? You could just say that primitives are stored directly in a variable. Such a value could never take any effect on other variables. No need to even mention it.

My guess is, that the spec wants to explicitly **allow references to immutable objects** (like in Python).

**So my question is:**

Why does the specification refer to immutable values rather than just saying "the value gets stored directly in the variable" (aka value type)?

Is it just to ensure that engine developers can implement it however they like? Or is it indeed just a very basic explanation that each variable is assigned to a value without being explicit about how this is technically implemented - but therefore you at least need the value to be immutable?

Comment: this says you can't do `5=6;`

Comment: Yeah, so I guess my question was: Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Suppose you have `var someString = 'FooBar';`. You also can't do: `someString[5] = 'z'`, or `someString.replace('Bar', 'Baz')`, in the sense that these operations won't affect the original string (but both will happily execute and may initially appear to work that way). But you can do `someString = 'FooBaz'`, or `someString = someString.replace('Bar', 'Baz')`.

Comment: Yeah that's true. It might also serve to clarify that wrapper classes are immutable as well.

Comment: Re "isn't that obvious", I guess it depends on the context.  Sure, it's not something anybody is likely to want to do, but there are ways it might be done if it's not explicitly barred.  So it makes sense as a foundational specification, because you need to specify even the really obvious when you're starting from scratch.  As an example of how it might be done, in the early oughts, I ran into a bug in a program compiled with a late-'90's Fortran compiler where we managed to redefine the value 0.0 to something non-zero, and much hilarity ensued.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd get this idea coming from C++ - there are no 'reference types'.   C++ has 'rvalues' and 'lvalues' (a concept inherited from C).     Variables in C++ may be declared as references by using a reference qualifier `&` in a declaration (or even an rvalue-reference with `&&`),   however reference semantics are a compile-time property of a variable, not a property of the underlying type.    I think the description here is likely closer to the C concept of rvalues/lvalues than the concept of reference/value types. (variables are lvalues, whereas primitive literals are rvalues).

Comment: @Craig interesting side note, thanks for sharing. On the other hand, specification like the one of PHP go the other route and say that VSTOREs are always holding copies of values (may it be primitives or references). But maybe Javascript just wants to be more precise here and rule out any edge-cases / allow any implementation.

Comment: @BenCottrell yes, you are right - I was simplifying C++ in that regard - but the underlying concept is similar (pointers are values as well and they are stored in the variable).

Comment: It seems common sense that a value like 123 cannot be changed to 124, for example. But if you had started out your career in FORTRAN many, many years ago you would know that common sense doesn't always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript is specified at a higher level than languages like C++, giving more implementation freedom as long as it conforms to the required semantics.

For example, ECMAScript does not specify whether values are stored on heap or stack and whether they are stored as pointers or direct values. The implementation can choose the most appropriate strategy, and may even change strategy at runtime.

Mutability is significant because it affects what strategy is appropriate. For an immutable value, there is no observable difference between copying a pointer to the value or copying the value, so the implementation may choose a strategy based on performance. For mutable values, however, the implementation is basically required to use pointers when assigning, since changes to a mutable value should be observable through all variables the value is assigned to.

For an object which is ostensibly mutable, but not actually mutated during the course of the code, the engine might store it as value rather than pointer, but have a fallback strategy in case the object is mutated.

Modern JavaScript implementation use very sophisticated optimizations, where code is profiled at runtime, and "hot" areas recompiled to more optimized code based on statistics. This could easily mean a temporary variable was entirely eliminated and a short-lived value purely lived in a register. An implementation requirement that variables should be stored in memory in a certain form would prevent such optimization.

So in short, ECMAScript does not specify such implementation details, since it would put unnecessary constraints on the implementation.

Comment: Thank you. That explanation helped me a lot. So, the emphasize on immutability lies in the fact, that primitives might be implemented as pointers? Because for direct storage - immutability is a given and would not need mentioning. Also I would like to ask you, what mental model you use when copying a primitive - do you imagine coyping a value or a pointer?

Comment: @tweekz: You can have mutable value types in some languages. ECMAScript focus on semantics like identity and mutability because it gives the implementation greater freedom. In JavaScript and similar languages, I think of variables as bindings between a name and a value.

Comment: So if I do something like let a = 4 and let b = a -> do think of a and b pointing to the same value or to separate instances of a value that are equal?

Answer (score 1):

> "You could just say that primitives are stored directly in a variable.
> Such a value could never take any effect on other variables"

That's not true. This is where the metaphor that describes a variable as a little box that stores values breaks down. Speaking in general terms (that is, the following is not specific to a particular language), variables are abstractions. Under the hood, the actual value resides somewhere in memory, and during execution of various low level instructions, at certain points registers or other memory locations contain values that represent offsets to that address, or store the address itself, etc. The process might involve a whole bunch of copying of values back and forth, to and from temporary locations, operating on these temporary values, and so on - this whole intricate dance that helps maintain the illusion that has been dreamt up by the designers of the higher level language. The details of this are different between languages and compilers. Variables as you know them from the source code might not exist as such in the compiled code.

But coming back to the higher-lever notion: you can have variables that are *aliases*. Two technically distinct named labels that refer to the same value (and thus both "see" the changes to the underlying value). That's because the value is not "in" the variable. In JavaScript, you might create an alias by creating a closure over a variable.

Note that aliases are *not* pointers. A pointer would be something like a variable that refers to a value (a number) that itself represents an address to a completely different memory location.

**Value Types vs Reference Types**

It's a little tricky because the meaning of these terms can vary to some extent across languages, and can be tied to the idiosyncrasies of each language. But roughly speaking, it is not given that a value type (or a type with value copy semantics) is immutable.

The Java/C# notion of value vs reference types does not cleanly map to how types work in C++, in that in C++ these semantics have to some extent be built by you. In C++, if you create an instance of a class, it's a *value type* (think of the case where you're not using `new`). However, you can normally mutate its state (you can change parts of it in memory, and the object itself will retain its identity and "continuity of existence", Ship of Theseus–style). If you want instances of a class to be immutable by design, you have to, well, design it that way yourself.

If the type is made immutable, you can't modify the instance - if you wanted a slightly altered version, you'd have to *replace* the entire instance with a different object that has the desired state. That is, you'd have to make the variable refer to a different object.

Now, in a way, the combo of {a pointer + the pointed-to instance} is a reference type (in the Java/C# sense), but the pointer itself (viewed on its own) has value semantics and is passed around by copy. As before, if the pointed-to type is immutable, you can't modify the underlying instance itself - if you want to change something about it, you have to *replace* it with a different object, and change the value of the pointer (change what the value refers to).

Immutable primitive types are conceptually unchangeable in the same sense. E.g., consider an integer: under "normal" circumstances, you don't *mutate* parts of an integer value in place (furthermore, conceptually, it doesn't even have parts). You just make the variable refer to some other integer. Now, in reality, an integer is typically a multi-byte value; C++ allows you to bypass the primitive abstraction, and fiddle with the underlying bytes in place. JavaScript does not ("The language does not offer utilities to mutate primitive values"). You can fiddle with the bits, but it results in a modified copy.

And the fact that something is immutable by design also allows compilers/interpreters to assign the same underling value to different variables under various circumstances (e.g. in a type system where strings are immutable, two unrelated string variables that happen to have the same content might refer to the same underlying memory, precisely because the content can't be changed). Again, coming back to the initial point, the value is not literally "in the variable".

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I do understand that internally a lot of magic might happen. Especially with abstract / interpreted languages (and even with compiled ones). But speaking as a general mental model, I find it way more intuitive to just think of variables holding a value, rather than referencing immutable objects (in case of primitives). It just adds an additional layer of indirection. So basically I am confused, if my mental model is acceptable for JavaScript.

Comment: @tweekz For the most purposes, that mental model is fine. Where you have to be careful is in some specific scenarios and edge cases, where the higher level abstractions become "leaky". Like the alias being created in a closure, and you weren't expecting that. Or, say, when doing something perf. critical with strings and you run into performance issues - if you're not aware strings are immutable, and every change creates a new string, so you get slowdowns, you might now know how to begin to tackle the problem. (The string thing is not JavaScript specific, though. E.g. its true of C# as well).

Comment: With values stored directly in variables you will end up copying those values anyway. Actually, implementations like V8 apply both models. In case of small integers, they store them directly in the variable (as a tagged pointer). Strings actually are immutable Objects on the Heap.

Comment: @tweekz - that's what I mean by "variables are an abstraction" and "primitives are an abstraction". What's actually happening under the hood depends on implementation details. Strings are counted/conceptualized as "primitives" on the language level, but implementation-wise, things are more complicated.

Comment: @tweekz - I guess you may be interpreting the MDN article as a text that's describing how things work under the hood, but its not doing that - it describes what these things mean on the language specification level. E.g. they don't consider strings to be objects at the language levels. For example, you can't add a property to a string the way you can add it to proper JS objects, arrays and functions.

Comment: I guess I'm having somewhat of a "programming-existential-crises" in the sense, that I grew up with the "value in a memory - either primitive or reference" model, which I guess makes perfect sense from a historical computer science point of view. And while there might be a lot of other ways to achieve that behavior, I find that to be both, clean and easy to picture. Differentiating just by Mutability somehow only makes sense when you are dealing with references, which is an additional layer of indirection and thus harder to figure out while writing code.

Comment: @tweekz - "I guess I'm having somewhat of a "programming-existential-crises"" - I know that feels uncomfortable, but embrace it, it's actually a good thing - 'cause that's how growth happens. The crisis stems from being confronted with a slightly different paradigm that doesn't fit neatly in your preexisting mental model, so it compels you to work through it, and in the end that very act is what will enrich your understanding and make you an even better developer. 1/2

Comment: And you know, you can be "of two minds" here -  you *don't* have to throw away the old way of thinking. In many instances, it will still be good enough. As you work through the "crisis", you get better at recognizing where the edge cases are.  Like how, in physics, they don't throw away the simpler Newtonian gravity for the more accurate, but much more complicated General Relativity of Einstein - for everyday scenarios, they use the simpler way of thinking (and calculating), and reserve GR for extreme environments, like near a black hole, where Newtonian conceptualization breaks down. 2/2